# If else statements (beginner)

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a school assignment and for the life of me I cannot figure out why my else statement is not printing out the line I need it to.  If user inputs anything other than 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5, I need it to print invalid entry.

Here is what I have so far:

```
/**
 *Proj2.java
 *This project will be able to ask the user which category
  they fall in to and then ask how many tickets they want and 
  if they want parking added.
  It will then calculate the total cost for all tickets, with discounts
  and parking.
*/

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Proj2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
  {  Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);

final double general = 80;
final double parking = 25;
final double alumniDiscount = .1;
final double facultyDiscount = .15;
final double militaryDiscount = .2;
final double studentDiscount = .5;
//This declares all the constants for this program

int numberOfTickets = 0;
int selection = 0;
double ticketsPrice = 0;
double finalCost = 0;
//declares the variables

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

System.out.println("\n**Welcome to the KSU Homecoming ticketing app for Fall 2014**");
System.out.println("\t -----Show your Purple Pride!-----\n\n\n");

//this displays the header for the customer

System.out.println("Please select from the following categories:\n\n" 
+ "1) Student\n" 
+ "2) Alumni\n" 
+ "3) Faculty & Staff\n"
+ "4) Military\n"
+ "5) General Public\n");

//this list out all the options the customer can choose from

System.out.print("Selection: ");
selection = Integer.parseInt (s.nextLine());


System.out.print("\nPlease enter the number of tickets you would like to purchase: ");
numberOfTickets = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());


System.out.print("\nWould you like to purchase a parking pass for the game?\n"
+ "Select Y or N: ");
char parkingChoice= (s.nextLine()).charAt(0);

//questions for the user to input their answer


if (selection == 1) {
ticketsPrice = ((general - (general * studentDiscount)) * numberOfTickets);
}

else if (selection == 2) {
ticketsPrice = ((general - (general * alumniDiscount)) * numberOfTickets);
}

else if (selection == 3) {
ticketsPrice = ((general - (general * facultyDiscount)) * numberOfTickets);
}

else if (selection == 4) {
ticketsPrice = ((general - (general * militaryDiscount)) * numberOfTickets);
}

else if (selection == 5) {
ticketsPrice = general * numberOfTickets;
}

else  {
System.out.println("Invalid Category selection");
}


//calculations based on which selection the user chooses

if (parkingChoice == 'Y' || parkingChoice == 'y') {
finalCost = ticketsPrice + parking;
System.out.println("\n\nYou ordered " + numberOfTickets + " tickets" + " with parking for a total      cost of: $" + df.format(finalCost)+"\n");
}
else if (parkingChoice == 'N' || parkingChoice == 'n') {
finalCost = ticketsPrice;
System.out.println("\n\nYou ordered " + numberOfTickets + " tickets" + " without parking for a   total cost of: $" + df.format(finalCost)+"\n");
}

//whether to add parking or not


System.out.println("Enjoy the game and a Wildcat Victory!");


  } // end main 
} // end class

}
```

It complies and works for the math, just not my error message. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you input s as another int (i.e. 7) and you don't get "Invalid Category selection"

Comment: *That* code *will* display an "Invalid" message (when it does the discount calculations) if "6" has been entered. Check that it *is* compiling and the result of the latest compilation *is* what is being run.

Comment: I put 6 can got "Invalid Category selection"

Comment: Your code would be a lot easier to read if you indented it properly.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a Switch statement instead of the IFs, or does that go outside the project?

Comment: It will eventually display "Invalid Category selection" if `6` is entered, but only after the number of tickets and parking pass questions.  The order of statements should be changed.

Comment: I do get an invalid selection on inputting eg 10,7 etc. Maybe the question you are asking is that if you enter the selection which is not permissible you would not want the user to input any data ?

Comment: (Also, as I minor change I would use: `general * (1 - discount) * numberOfTickets` for the calculations, wrapped inside a method.)

Answer (score 2):

Your program works just fine. I think the issue is that you should check the validity of the input every time it is entered and not after all data has been typed in by the user:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    final double general = 80;
    final double parking = 25;
    final double alumniDiscount = .1;
    final double facultyDiscount = .15;
    final double militaryDiscount = .2;
    final double studentDiscount = .5;
    // This declares all the constants for this program

    int numberOfTickets = 0;
    int selection = 0;
    double ticketsPrice = 0;
    double finalCost = 0;
    // declares the variables

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    System.out.println("\n**Welcome to the KSU Homecoming ticketing app for Fall 2014**");
    System.out.println("\t -----Show your Purple Pride!-----\n\n\n");

    // this displays the header for the customer

    System.out.println("Please select from the following categories:\n\n" + "1) Student\n" + "2) Alumni\n" + "3) Faculty & Staff\n" + "4) Military\n" + "5) General Public\n");

    // this list out all the options the customer can choose from

    System.out.print("\nPlease enter the number of tickets you would like to purchase: ");
    numberOfTickets = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());

    if (numberOfTickets < 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid number of tickets");
        return;
    }

    System.out.print("Selection: ");
    selection = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());

    // questions for the user to input their answer

    if (selection == 1)
    {
        ticketsPrice = ((general - (general * studentDiscount)) * numberOfTickets);
    }

    else if (selection == 2)
    {
        ticketsPrice = ((general - (general * alumniDiscount)) * numberOfTickets);
    }

    else if (selection == 3)
    {
        ticketsPrice = ((general - (general * facultyDiscount)) * numberOfTickets);
    }

    else if (selection == 4)
    {
        ticketsPrice = ((general - (general * militaryDiscount)) * numberOfTickets);
    }

    else if (selection == 5)
    {
        ticketsPrice = general * numberOfTickets;
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Category selection");
        return;
    }



    System.out.print("\nWould you like to purchase a parking pass for the game?\n" + "Select Y or N: ");
    char parkingChoice = (s.nextLine()).charAt(0);

    if (parkingChoice == 'Y' || parkingChoice == 'y')
    {
        finalCost = ticketsPrice + parking;
        System.out.println("\n\nYou ordered " + numberOfTickets + " tickets" + " with parking for a total      cost of: $" + df.format(finalCost) + "\n");
    }
    else if (parkingChoice == 'N' || parkingChoice == 'n')
    {
        finalCost = ticketsPrice;
        System.out.println("\n\nYou ordered " + numberOfTickets + " tickets" + " without parking for a   total cost of: $" + df.format(finalCost) + "\n");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid parking choice");
        return;

    }
    // whether to add parking or not

    System.out.println("Enjoy the game and a Wildcat Victory!");

}
```

PS: It would be so much nicer with some `switch` statements :)

**Edit**: Change code to set `numberOfTickets` first. Thanks to CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc for noticing that.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you validate the input before asking for the next line of input? (i.e. move the input scanning code inline with the logic flow)

Comment: Please leave comments on the comments section.

Comment: If you think about my comment, the answer I'm suggesting should be obvious

Comment: @khriskooper Don't make questions sounds like comments. *Assertively write it as an answer with statements*; providing a code changes/examples also helps. (Note the difference in reception with the currently up-voted answer, yet the OP's statements are still not clarified. It might very well be he is running an old build..)

Answer (score 0):

Just do a simple check as soon as you get the `selection` input:

```
//beginning code goes here
System.out.print("Selection: ");
selection = Integer.parseInt (s.nextLine());

//simple check
if(selection < 1 || selection > 5){
    System.out.println("Invalid Category selection");
}else{
    System.out.print("\nPlease enter the number of tickets you would like to purchase: ");
    numberOfTickets = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
    System.out.print("\nWould you like to purchase a parking pass for the game?\n" + "Select Y or N: ");
    char parkingChoice= (s.nextLine()).charAt(0);

    switch(selection){
        case 1:
            ticketsPrice = ((general - (general * studentDiscount)) * numberOfTickets);
            break;
        case 2:
            ticketsPrice = ((general - (general * alumniDiscount)) * numberOfTickets);
            break;
        case 3:
            ticketsPrice = ((general - (general * facultyDiscount)) * numberOfTickets);
            break;
        case 4:
            ticketsPrice = ((general - (general * militaryDiscount)) * numberOfTickets);
            break;
        case 5:
            ticketsPrice = general * numberOfTickets;
            break;
        default://this case is not needed.  i kept it in so its easier to understand.
            System.out.println("Invalid Category selection");
            break;
    }

    //calculations based on which selection the user chooses
    if (parkingChoice == 'Y' || parkingChoice == 'y') {
        finalCost = ticketsPrice + parking;
        System.out.println("\n\nYou ordered " + numberOfTickets + " tickets" + " with parking for a total      cost of: $" + df.format(finalCost)+"\n");
    }
    else if (parkingChoice == 'N' || parkingChoice == 'n') {
        finalCost = ticketsPrice;
        System.out.println("\n\nYou ordered " + numberOfTickets + " tickets" + " without parking for a   total cost of: $" + df.format(finalCost)+"\n");
    }
    //whether to add parking or not
    System.out.println("Enjoy the game and a Wildcat Victory!");
}
//ending code goes here.
```

**Note**:  @ortis original answer won't work correctly (although it got upvotes :/ ) because `numberOfTickets` isn't assigned by user until later in his/her solution.

Comment: Default case is not need as  you have the if check about !

Comment: @Aeshang I know.  I just put it in as a reflection of the original code.  It makes it easier for OP to follow.